# How to force WebAPI to use JSON.net 6.0.3 instead of 4.5?

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

After adding `WebAPI` and register it in `Global.asax`.

We find our web app breaks at this line:

```
Line 17:             GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

After some checkup, I find we are using `Json.net 6` in this `MVC 5.1` application. Does it mean we have to downgrade to `Json.net 4.5` for `WebAPI` to work?

---

In my `.csproj` file, there is only one entry:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

When I look into my `Json.NET` in `Manage NuGet Packages`, it also says my `Json.NET` is version 6.0.3.

In addition, there is already the `bindingRedirect` statement in my `web.config`.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But, if I look into the `references` of the web project inside visual studio. The path of `Newtonsoft.Json` points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll` but `Copy Local` is false.

How can that be? How can we handle this conflict?

Comment: Are you sure that code is correct and it shouldn't be `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`?

Comment: That register statement is from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api#webhost.

Is it correct?

Comment: Make that correction as DavidG suggested. Same error.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add a binding redirection in your web.config (possibly merge with your existing binding redirections):

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that is not the solution. 'cause this statement is there already. But thanks for the input.

Comment: @Blaise That's wield because I had exactly the same issue (same exception on same line) a few days ago and it was the solution.

Comment: @Blaise Have you tried reinstalling the NuGet package and setting `CopyLocal` to `true`? It's `true` in my project.

Comment: @Blaise This actually worked for me, but be sure to put in 6.0.0.0 and not the exact version.

Comment: This worked for me except for a minor tweak in that config:
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />

Answer (score 5):

The redirect did not work for me until I update the Web Api to a recent version:

```
PM> update-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' from version '4.0.20710.0' to '4.0.30506.0' in project 'TestProject.Api'.
```

---

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here is my fix.

Well one thing I don't know is how the Json.net reference points to the dll in the `Blend` folder in the first place.

I tried to re-NuGet but found it rather inconvenient because WebApi and WebGrease are all dependent on it.

So I just went ahead and deleted that reference. That of course breaks everything related.

When adding the reference back, I simply Add Reference by browsing to the dll under the `/.package` folder inside this project.

It works!

Pretty brutal? Just make sure we checked

- .csproj
- Web.Config
- the property in the Reference entry in VS

Dare to try after all bases are covered.